# Rectangle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation

Can you help me. to obtain this:
[image]

I tried to do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle
          (2,1) coordinate(C) node[above]{} -- (0,0) coordinate(A) node[below]              {}
          (0,1) coordinate(D) node[,above]{} -- (2,0) coordinate(B) node[below]{y};
 \path ($(B)!0.5!(D)$)--(D)node[midway,below,right=0.5mm]{$x-y$};
  \path ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)--(C)node[midway,below]{$x+y$};   
  \path  ($(A)!0.5!(D)$)--(A)node[midway,left=0.5mm]{$x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please how to get the dashed lines?

Comment: over the past few weeks, you have asked several questions and received answers to them as well. So if the answers were useful to you, consider accepting them by clicking the tick mark below the votting button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    % Dashed part (top left to bottom right)
    \draw[dashed]  node[below]{\small $y$}(0,0)--(0,1)--(-2,1);
    % Solid part (top right to bottom left)
    \draw[solid] (-2,1)--node[pos=0.5, left]{\small $x$}(-2,0)--(0,0);
    % Diagonal (top left to bottom right)
    \draw[solid] (-2,1)--(0,0) node[pos=0.2,rotate=-25, below]{\small $x-y$};
    % Diagonal (top right to bottom left)
    \draw[solid] (-2,0)--(0,1) node[pos=0.8,rotate=25, below]{\small $x+y$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, 
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize, 
                           pos=0.7, sloped}
                    ]
\draw   (0,0) -- (0,1)  node[above] {$x$}  
              -- (2,0)  node[below] {$y$} -- (0,0)
              edge ["$x+y$"]        (2,1)
        (2,0) edge ["$x-y$"]        (0,1);
\draw[densely dashed]
        (0,1) -| (2,.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

from your sketch is not clear if `X` is name of upper left corner or is name of left rectangle border. If the case is later, then tuse the following changes in `tikzpicture` code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, 
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize,sloped}
                    ]
\draw   (0,0) edge ["$x$",pos=0.5] (0,1)
              -- (2,0) node[below] {$y$} -- (0,0)
              edge ["$x+y$",pos=0.7]        (2,1)
        (2,0) edge ["$x-y$",pos=0.7]        (0,1);
\draw[densely dashed]
        (0,1) -| (2,.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\def\x{2.5} \def\y{5}
\draw[dashed] (\y,\x)--(0,\x) (\y,\x)--(\y,0);
\draw (\y,\x)
--(0,0)  node[sloped,below,pos=.3]{$x+y$}
--(\y,0) node[below]{$y$}
--(0,\x) node[sloped,below,pos=.7]{$x-y$} node[left]{$x$}
--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```